# Windows 7 doesn't have Speakers on Playback Options

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, windows-10

After reinstalling Windows 7 I don't have sound and after installing an Audio Driver such as download Audio Driver from `ASUS` website and reinstall that after uninstalling current driver or `Install/Update` Driver by `Driver Pack Solution 15.04` I don't have Speakers item on PlayBack options.

[image]

After click on volume I see this image:

[image]

Audio hardware doesn't have a problem. After boot up Ubuntu operating System my sound card works correctly and I have not any problem with that :|

**My System specifications:**

MainBoard: Asus M2V

tested Windows: Windows 7 - Windows 8 Windows 8.2 - Windows 10

Comment: I used to get this all the time. Only solution I found was to plug the speakers into the headphone socket. Are you able to [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/1010036/edit) your question with the specifications of your PC?

Comment: Sounds like a driver issue, try re installing your drivers, should be available through the asus website.

Comment: @Burgi Problem Solved, i'm posted reply

Answer (score 0):

**Problem Solved**

my main board sound card driver dont work on windows 64 bit even if I download 64 bit driver for windows, after installing windows 7 32 bit my sound card work correctly :|